# Glassfish Developer Profile

Tags: deployment, glassfish, glassfish-3

I would like to enable auto-deploy on glassfish.

Thanks to Nacho for pointing out my mismatch of version in the original question

<strike>I have looked at this link:</strike>

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4337/fvxze/index.html

and it says I need to do this as a developer profile. I do not hink I have a developer profile set up on glassfish as I cannot see the "Application Server Component" it tells me to

Is there a way I can tell which profile I have? Is there a way I can amend my existing profile to a developer one so I can enable auto-deployment?

I guess the question is now how can I change the auto-deploy settings on Glassfish 3. There is an auto-deploy directory but what if I want to change the polling time etc.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying it on glassfish 3 or 2.1? because that guide is for 2.1...

Comment: well spotted. I am using Glassfish 3. Let me amend my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To enable or disable auto-deployment from the GlassFish Server Administration Console, navigate to the Domain node and then click the Applications Configuration tab."

As specified here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2431/abedo.html